# How to know when it is subjunctive or not

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, subjunctive-mood, mood

In this line: God save the earth! … and the Queen too if God so chooses.  Was the word “chooses” correctly used?

Comment: Hello, Emily. The formulaic subjunctive exclamations are archaic, and few and far between. There are no Google hits in searches for either "and the Queen too if God so choose" or "and the Queen too if God so chooses". The switch from subjunctive to indicative is jarring, but perhaps less so than the startling 'if God so choose'.  I'm not sure that there's a correct fit here. Perhaps 'if God should so choose'. Or 'if it be His will'. Or 'if it's his will'.

Comment: Requests for proofreading are not [on-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, so technically it would be nice to focus your question a bit more. The title asks *whether* it's subjunctive (see FumbleFingers' link; "save" is but "chooses" is not) and the body simply asks whether it's correct. I suspect that your real question is whether it's okay to shift the mood like that; if so, could you edit to make that clear?

Comment: Yes, the word _chooses_ was correctly used. The present subjunctive is not used after _if_ any longer. Mostly it's restricted to formulas and famous quotations.

Comment: @JohnLawler your comment addressed my question.  Gracias!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, That was what I thought.  Thank you.

Comment: @AndyBonner, u were right.  But u did answered my question.  Thanks.